# Adding multiple different types of records in some collection and sorting them

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5, json.net

I want to send a collection of two different Collections as a Json but in a sorted format. I am not able to do it with Linq. Need little help.And also is there any better way. Thank you!

**Here is my action.**

```
    public ActionResult GetAllJobPosts()
    {
        var Institutes = new List<Institute>()
        {
            new Institute(){InstituteId="ins1",InstituteName="name1",Location="Mumbai"},
            new Institute(){InstituteId="ins2",InstituteName="name2",Location="Navi Mumbai"},
            new Institute(){InstituteId="ins3",InstituteName="name3",Location="Thiruvananthpuram"}
        };

        var Companys = new List<Company>()
        {
            new Company(){CompanyId="com1",CompanyName="comName1",Location="Mumbai"},
            new Company(){CompanyId="com2",CompanyName="comName2",Location="Navi Mumbai"},
            new Company(){CompanyId="com3",CompanyName="comName3",Location="Mumbai"}
        };

        var Organizations = new List<Organization>() 
        {
            new Organization(){OrganizationId="org1",OrganizationName="orgName1",Location="Navi Mumbai"},
            new Organization(){OrganizationId="org2",OrganizationName="orgName2",Location="Navi Mumbai"},
            new Organization(){OrganizationId="org3",OrganizationName="orgName3",Location="Mumbai"},
        };
        var CompanyJobPosts = new List<CompanyJobPost>()
        {
            new CompanyJobPost(){CompanyId="com1",CompanyJobPostId="com1jp1",CreatedOn=System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2),JobDiscription="Tester",KeySkils="Sylanium"},
            new CompanyJobPost(){CompanyId="com1",CompanyJobPostId="com1jp2",CreatedOn=System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3),JobDiscription="Developer",KeySkils="C#"},
            new CompanyJobPost(){CompanyId="com2",CompanyJobPostId="com2jp1",CreatedOn=System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5),JobDiscription="Tester",KeySkils="Sylanium"},
            new CompanyJobPost(){CompanyId="com2",CompanyJobPostId="com2jp2",CreatedOn=System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-6),JobDiscription="Developer",KeySkils="C#"},
            new CompanyJobPost(){CompanyId="com3",CompanyJobPostId="com3jp1",CreatedOn=System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7),JobDiscription="Tester",KeySkils="Sylanium"},
            new CompanyJobPost(){CompanyId="com3",CompanyJobPostId="com3jp2",CreatedOn=System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-8),JobDiscription="Developer",KeySkils="C#"}
        };
        var InstituteJobPosts = new List<InstituteJobPost>() 
        {
            new InstituteJobPost(){InstituteId="ins1",InstituteJobPostId="ins1jp1",CreatedOn=System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),JobDiscription="Trainer",KeySkils="C#",ExtraField="MDifferent"},
            new InstituteJobPost(){InstituteId="ins1",InstituteJobPostId="ins1jp2",CreatedOn=System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-8),JobDiscription="Developer",KeySkils="Java",ExtraField="MDifferent"},
            new InstituteJobPost(){InstituteId="ins2",InstituteJobPostId="ins2jp1",CreatedOn=System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),JobDiscription="Trainer",KeySkils="Java",ExtraField="MDifferent"},
            new InstituteJobPost(){InstituteId="ins2",InstituteJobPostId="ins2jp2",CreatedOn=System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-8),JobDiscription="Developer",KeySkils=".Net",ExtraField="MDifferent"},
            new InstituteJobPost(){InstituteId="ins3",InstituteJobPostId="ins3jp1",CreatedOn=System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),JobDiscription="Trainer",KeySkils="C#",ExtraField="MDifferent"},
            new InstituteJobPost(){InstituteId="ins3",InstituteJobPostId="ins3jp2",CreatedOn=System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-8),JobDiscription="Developer",KeySkils="Java",ExtraField="MDifferent"}
        };
        var allJobPosts=new List<object>();
        foreach (var item in CompanyJobPosts)
        {
            allJobPosts.Add(new { JType = "Company", JobPost = item });
        } 
        foreach (var item in InstituteJobPosts)
        {
            allJobPosts.Add(new { JType = "Institute", JobPost = item });
        }
        //var allJobPostsOrderdByDate=??
        return Json(allJobPosts, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

**Here are My Models just to make it simple.**

```
namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
public class Company
{
    public string CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
}
public class Organization
{
    public string OrganizationId { get; set; }
    public string OrganizationName { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
}
public class Institute
{
    public string InstituteId { get; set; }
    public string InstituteName { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
}
public class CompanyJobPost
{
    public string CompanyJobPostId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string KeySkils { get; set; }
    public string JobDiscription { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
}
public class OrganizationJobPost
{
    public string OrganizationJobPostId { get; set; }
    public string OrganizationId { get; set; }
    public string KeySkils { get; set; }
    public string JobDiscription { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string ExtraField2 { get; set; }
}
public class InstituteJobPost
{
    public string InstituteJobPostId { get; set; }
    public string InstituteId { get; set; }
    public string KeySkils { get; set; }
    public string JobDiscription { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string ExtraField { get; set; }
}
```

}

**And finally my sweet view**

```
<input name="GetAllJobPosts" id="GetAllJobPosts" type="submit" value="Search Jobs">
<ul id="JobPostList"></ul>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#GetAllJobPosts").click(function () {
    var actionUrl = '@Url.Action("GetAllJobPosts", "Default")';
    $.getJSON(actionUrl, displayDetailData);
});

function displayDetailData(response) {
    if (response != null) {

        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            $("#JobPostList").append("<li>" + response[i].JType + " " + (response[i].JobPost).CreatedOn + "</li>")
        }
    }
}
```

Thank You!

Comment: So, what's wrong with it? What isn't working? Where does it fail?

Comment: I want to send the final data in sorted manner. I mean collection containing both institute collection and company collection but sorted by date, or some thing.

Comment: And why can't you sort using linq?

Comment: Sorry by sort I mean sorted in ascending order.
`var allJobPostsOrderdByDate=from jobposts in allJobPosts
                            orderby jobposts??`

Comment: allJobPosts is a list of object type and how can i get variables in object further it is anonymous type, so can't cast it to any type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, I can only assume the following, so will do my best to point you in the correct direction:

You do not have a common object of inheritance between the two - that is, you wish to sort them on property **x**, but property **x**, is not defined to exist in both.

So, solution? Easy: add a common interface, class or abstract class between the two that has the property you wish to sort by, then sort by it:

```
public interface IJobPost
{
    DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

Then modify your three existing objects:

```
public class CompanyJobPost : IJobPost
{
    public string CompanyJobPostId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string KeySkils { get; set; }
    public string JobDiscription { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
}
public class OrganizationJobPost : IJobPost
{
    public string OrganizationJobPostId { get; set; }
    public string OrganizationId { get; set; }
    public string KeySkils { get; set; }
    public string JobDiscription { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string ExtraField2 { get; set; }
}
public class InstituteJobPost : IJobPost
{
    public string InstituteJobPostId { get; set; }
    public string InstituteId { get; set; }
    public string KeySkils { get; set; }
    public string JobDiscription { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string ExtraField { get; set; }
}
```

Lastly, the action:

```
var allJobPosts=new List<IJobPost>();
// Add other posts to allJobPosts here.
var allJobPostsOrderdByDate = allJobPosts.OrderBy(x => x.CreatedOn).ToList();
```

Note: Code is untested. LINQ query may or may not work. Did this all from memory.

Edit: You can also share any other properties you wish to force between the three of them. That is what an **interface** or **abstract class** is for. That also means you can share **Description** or other properties.